# Vaadin 19 stopping tomcatserver

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I'm mantaining a vaadin application with a backend neo4j. Two tomcats (9.0.55) on the same server (using ports 80 and 5005 for the backend)

When I use it intensively, loading lots of data, vaadin crashes and tomcat stop responding.

If I check catalina.out log I can see some errors before te crash:

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xee0x010x000x000xea0x030x03R/S0x0e0xa3-s0xc0{0xf00x88l0xe3\0xb30xcf0xf90x1b0x870xb90x11=0xab0xaf)0xf10xdd0x890x13+0x930x11 ]. HTTP method names must be tokens

2022-11-10 08:55:31.015 ERROR 5115 --- [0.1-8009-exec-7] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      :
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

Exception in thread "ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-Poller" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

10-Nov-2022 09:45:19.259 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation. Stack trace of request processing thread:[

I don't know which of the errors causes the web server to crash but it seems that only tomcat of the frontend is stopping the service. Backend is still running.

Could incrementing max threads resolve this issue?

Many thanks
JV

All webpage is shutting down. I have to restart tomcat frontend to restore the service.

Comment: The most likely case is a leak or excessive loading of data.  Monitor the container. Increase the heap and see what is happening. If it happens after some time regardless the traffic, it's most likely a leak.  If it is happening due to some user action it's most likely loading to much.

Comment: And the error there is `OutOfMemoryError` - maybe you see a GC death spiral first. But in general it's _very_ unlikely that there is a generic problem an outsider can solve. If you really think, that Vaadin 19 is the sole culprit, then I'd suggest updating away from the no longer supported version. 23 is the new LTS version.

Comment: How much Xmx and Xms did you specifiy for your Tomcat

Comment: It's a bitnami server and I see on the folder /opt/bitnami/tomcat/conf/bitnami some scripts for the heap space: Currently -Xms2G -Xmx4G but testing it with -Xms4G -Xmx8G I saw issues too

Answer (score 0):

If it fails with Xmx4G and also with Xmx8G, then it looks like there is a memory leak (and more memory will only postpone the problem).

The memory leak may be caused by the framework, or by your own code. For instance, just keeping a reference to one component will cause the whole `HttpSession` to be reachable. You may run into this scenario if you keep references to components that outlive the session (e.g. components subscribe to some global event and forgot to unsuscribe when detached).
It may help to run a [memory dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture) and analyze what is the cause of the OutOfMemoryError.

As @cfrick noted, Vaadin 19 is [no longer maintained](https://vaadin.com/roadmap) (last release June 2021). Some memory leaks have been fixed after Vaadin 19 end-of-life:

- [Memory leak on adding and removing components](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13851) (fixed on 22+)
- [Memory leak: button's ShortcutRegistration is not removed after detach](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11939)  (fixed on 22+)

Upgrading to Vaadin 22 shouldn't be too difficult (although you may run into some changes that affect custom styling of components, see [Upgrade Guide](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/upgrading/upgrade-tool)).
Vaadin 23 requires Java 11, and there are some changes in the frontend building (23.1 defaults to npm instead of pnpm, and 23.2 defaults to vite instead of webpack)